Skipping the previous number of the main list in the sublist
I'm trying to achieve a specific numbering format for nested lists in LaTeX with enumitem. Here's what I'm aiming for:
1.Main item
2a. Sub-item
2b. Sub-item
3. Main item
I tried with this code:
\newlist{mainlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mainlist]{label=\arabic*., itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

\newlist{sublist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[sublist]{label=\arabic{mainlisti}\alph*., itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

\begin{mainlist}
    \item Main item
    \begin{sublist}
        \item Sub-item
        \item Sub-item
    \end{sublist}
    \item Main item
\end{mainlist}

But it gives me : 
1.Main item
1a. Sub-item
1b. Sub-item
2.  Main item
If anyone has a solution. Thanks

You could use enumitem's before key to step the mainlist counter when starting a sublist. I guess also that an extra indentation in a sublist doesn't really make sense, so I removed it in the following example.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mainlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mainlist]{label=\arabic*., itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

\newlist{sublist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[sublist]{
    label=\arabic{mainlisti}\alph*.,
    itemsep=0pt,
    topsep=0pt,
    before=\stepcounter{mainlisti},
    leftmargin=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mainlist}
    \item Main item
    \begin{sublist}
        \item Sub-item
        \item Sub-item
    \end{sublist}
    \item Main item
\end{mainlist}
\end{document}

If you don't want to remove the extra indentation in sublist, just remove the line
leftmargin=0pt,

in the above.
